# Sequelize create method empty array

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I've implemented one-to-many relationship between `Order` and `Products`.

Order has more Products - Product belongs to Order

```
Product.belongsTo(Order, {
    as: 'order',
    foreignKey: 'order_id'
})
Order.hasMany(Product, {
    as: 'products',
    foreignKey: 'order_id'
})
```

When I create new `Order` with `create` method, returned object doesn't include array of empty `Products`.

I tried to use options for `create` method like this:

```
const newOrder = await Order.create({ }, {
        include: [{
            as: 'products',
            model: Product
        }]
    });

// products attribute in newOrder doesn't exist.
```

I expected object:

```
{
  id: 1;
  products: []
}
```

but only property `id` attribute was returned in this object - without `products` empty array.

Of course, if `findByPk` or `findAll` method with `include` option is used, products are also included. But it's useless query for this usage.

How to return also `products` without manual adding it to response object?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `products: []` to `create` option. This won't execute any `INSERT` query to `products` table but it will be returned as is.

```
const newOrder = await Order.create(
    { products: [] }, 
    {
        include: [{
            as: 'products',
            model: Product
        }]
    }
);
```